# compiler cannot find libvideogfx

Tags: configuration, cmake, static-libraries, configuration-files, configure

I am trying to install `libde265` from [source](https://github.com/strukturag/libde265/issues) but one of its *dependencies* is giving me problems. I also installed this *depedency* from source but I converted it to an rpm package before completing installation.

When I look for the location of this library I get:

`$ whereis libvideogfx
libvideogfx: /usr/local/lib/libvideogfx.la /usr/local/lib/libvideogfx.a /usr/local/lib/libvideogfx.so`

The flags I have added to the `./configure` command such as `LIBS` are not working and I don't know the root of the problem.

Comment: So you use `autotools` (run `./configure`) or CMake (run `cmake`)?

Comment: I am using `./configure` with `FLAG` options` before `cmake` because `libvideogfx` is needed to build an example program that comes with `libde265`. If `./configure` doesn't find `libvideogfx` then this example program called `sherlock` is disabled and not built.

Comment: Actually correction. I mean I am using `./configure` because there is no `CMakeList.txt` file.